# Why was my question about wrapper functions downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am surprised about how fast can users cast down votes. For example, I had to know about 'Wrapper functions in C++'. So, I searched the web, Wikipedia, etc. All I got was mostly relating to SQL or some other complex example program. So I asked the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900705/what-is-a-wrapper-function-in-c-c/14901007#14901007). I got some great answers, but I was flooded with down-votes and the topic was closed instantly. What was that I did wrong?

Comment: FYI, both C and C++ are much more complex than SQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question was simply too broad.  You were basically asking for someone to write a full tutorial on a topic for you.

Questions on SO are intended to be more specific than that.  There should be a "right" answer, a narrowly scoped targeted problem, as opposed to something vague like, "Just talk to me about this subject."

Based on the comments to your question, people also found it ambiguous as to what you meant, because the term itself that you wished to know about doesn't have a single, specific, meaning, particularly in the context of C/C++.